# Proof that the time derivative of arc length element is normal velocity times curvature

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, curvilinear-coordinates

I encountered the following formula to calculate the time variation of the arc length element $ds$ of a moving curve:

$ \partial_t ds = ds \,v_n k \,,$

where $v_n$ is the normal velocity of the curve and $k$ is the curvature.

Intuitively it makes sense, since if the curve is moving with a normal velocity and a curvature different from 0, then it will expand (or shrink), as in the following (terrible) drawing:

[image]

However, I would like to have a formal proof of that, could please anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is not correct as it stands. Imagine a particle going around a fixed circle faster and faster. Then obviously the rate of change of the tangential component of velocity is going to increase $ds$ as well.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yea, I guess you are right. So, assuming zero tangential velocity.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: If you take a normal variation of the original (let's assume arclength-parametrized) curve $\alpha$, you get
$$\beta_t(s) = \alpha(s) + tv(s)N(s),$$
where $T,N$ is the usual Frenet frame of the curve (so, in this case, $N$ points inward and your $v$ is negative).
Differentiating with respect to $s$ gives
\begin{align*}
\beta_t'(s) &= \alpha'(s) + tv'(s)N(s) + tv(s)(-\kappa(s)T(s)) \\&= (1-tv(s)\kappa(s))T(s) + tv'(s)N(s).
\end{align*}
Now the element of arclength  of $\beta_t$ is given by $\|\beta_t'(s)\|ds$, and so we want
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{t=0} \|\beta_t'(s)\|.$$
Since $\|\beta_t'(s)\|^2 = (1-tv(s)\kappa(s))^2 + (tv'(s))^2$, 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{t=0} \|\beta_t'(s)\|^2 = -2v(s)\kappa(s).$$
Therefore, by the chain rule, since $\|\beta_0'(s)\| = 1$, we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{t=0} \|\beta_t'(s)\| = -v(s)\kappa(s).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What is $\alpha(s)$ ?

Comment: My sloppiness. It's the arclength parametrization of the original curve.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting a bit confused... So what is $\beta_t(s)$? Wouldn't a variation of the original curve $\alpha(s)$ be expressed as $\alpha_t(s)$? Why we need another letter?

Comment: That's what I usually would use. But now I'm too lazy to switch them all. So, yes, $\beta_0 = \alpha$. Note, obviously, that for $t\ne 0$, $\beta_t$ is no longer arclength-parametrized.